# Why won't my do-while loop work? (multiple variables generated within function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, do-while

I have a function that generates two numbers. The function has a loop to keep generating numbers until it finds two whose product divides evenly into 24. This often works, but occasionally fails to do so.

```js
function randomBetween(min, max) {
  var ceiling = max + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - min)) + min;
}


function DOBINGenerateNonWhole() {
  var random;
  var random2;

  do {
    random = randomBetween(3, 36);
    random2 = randomBetween(3, 36);

  } while ((24 % (random * random2) != 0));
  return {
    random: random,
    random2: random2,

  }
}

var Span1 = DOBINGenerateNonWhole().random;
$('.Span1').html(Span1);

var Span2 = DOBINGenerateNonWhole().random2;
$('.Span2').html(Span2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Span1"></div>
<div class="Span2"></div>
```

Comment: You can paste your code into any editor which has an auto-formatting option (such as the one here on SO on JSFiddle, there are many more).

Comment: From JSFiddle, press "tidy", then select everything and press tab twice, and then you can copy it into a Markdown editor (like SO's)

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Does anyone have any advice that's actually relevant to the issue? I'd be much obliged.

Comment: @Snoops What does "occasionally fails to do so" mean? What _does_ it do when it fails to do so?

Comment: It generates two numbers whose product is not a factor of 24. (I just ran the JSFiddle a couple times, for example, and it set the two variables as 3 & 6.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running `DOBINGenerateNonWhole()` twice which is causing the issue. `random` and `random2` are not from the same invocation so there is no reason for their product to be a factor of 24

If you update your code to store the result it should work:

```
var result = DOBINGenerateNonWhole();
$('.Span1').html(result.random);
$('.Span2').html(result.random2);
```

Comment: Perfect - makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your input!